# Units of Einstein-Hilbert Action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, units, dimensional-analysis, action

Action is a quantity with units energy $\times$ time $=[kg \frac{m^2}{s}]$.
The Einstein-Hilbert action is
\begin{equation}
S_{EH}=\frac{c^4}{16\pi G}\int \sqrt{-g}R d^4x
\end{equation}
Looking only at the units in this action:
\begin{eqnarray}
[S] &=& \left[ \frac{\left(\frac{m}{s}\right)^4}{\frac{m^3}{kg s^2}}\right]\left[ m^{-2} m^4\right] \\
&=& \left[ \frac{kg \times m^3}{s^2}\right]
\end{eqnarray} 
Where the Ricci scalar has units of $m^{-2}$, and the spacetime metric has no units. Where does the extra unit of $m/s$ in my calculation come from, or did I forget to cancel something else?

Comment: Hint: is $\mathrm dx^0=\mathrm dt$ or $\mathrm dx^0=c\mathrm dt$?

Comment: So should my second term in brackets read $\left[ m^{-2} m^3s \right]$ for $[R][dxdydz][dt]$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform $c=1$ tho

Comment: @ocelouvsky that is true when working in natural units, but here I am explicitly working in SI units.

Comment: @0celouvsky ...and $8\pi G=1$

Comment: Bob, where exactly did you find this formula for the $S_{EH}$ action? I know it is quoted in Wikipedia - as I wrote in my answer below - but I wonder if you found it somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation you wrote - which is the same mentioned in Wikipedia, as of today - assumes that $dx^0=dt$.

It is however generally smarter to have all 4 coordinates share the same units, so most (I would say all) tensors have components sharing the same units. For example: in lorentian coordinates Riemann and Ricci tensors have units $[m^{-2}]$  and $g_{\mu\nu}$ is dimensionless.

Therefore it is customary to use $dx^0=cdt$, as you assumed.
But now the action becomes

\begin{equation}
S_{EH}=\frac{c^3}{16\pi G}\int \sqrt{-g}R d^4x
\end{equation}

as you can easily find - for example - in the classic Landau & Lifshitz Theory of Fields.